# Angular 4 - UI is not loading after retrieving data from server- Component variables only update after click the window

Tags: angular

I want to load data from server in my Angular app. I can able to get the data from the server. After load the the UI is not populate the html and If I click on the window it is loading the data immediately.

Strange Think is, it is not happening all time. Sometime HTML is loading Immediately without any issue. sometime not loading.

Here I am attaching My files.

**Dashboard.html**

```
<div class="dashboard-statistics">

<div fxLayout="column"
     [fxLayoutGap]="layoutGap['lt-md']" [fxLayoutGap.gt-md]="layoutGap['gt-md']">

  <div class="example-loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
      <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
  </div>

  <div  *ngIf="!isLoadingResults"  fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column"
       fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayout.lt-md="start stretch"
       [fxLayoutGap]="layoutGap['gt-md']" [fxLayoutGap.lt-md]="layoutGap['lt-md']"
       [fxFlex]="flexWidth['lt-sm']">

    <div fxLayout="row"
         fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
         [fxLayoutGap]="layoutGap['gt-md']" [fxLayoutGap.lt-md]="layoutGap['lt-md']"
         [fxFlex]="flexWidth['gt-md']" [fxFlex.lt-md]="flexWidth['lt-sm']" [fxFlex.gt-sm]="flexWidth['gt-sm']" [fxFlex.gt-md]="flexWidth['gt-md']">
      <div class="widget" fxFlex="auto" fxFlex.gt-xs>
        <vr-state-widget property="Fee Due Today" value="{{ data.studentFeeDueToday }}" icon=""

                         backgroundColor="linear-gradient(60deg, #8C99E0, #6572B8)" textColor="white"></vr-state-widget>
      </div>

      <div class="widget" fxFlex="auto" fxFlex.gt-xs>
        <vr-state-widget property="Fee Due Students" value="{{ data.studentFeeDue }}" icon=""
                         backgroundColor="linear-gradient(60deg, #4DD0E2, #4CA8BA)" textColor="white"></vr-state-widget>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTE_TRANSITION } from '../../app.animation';
import * as fromRoot from '../../reducers/index';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { BadInput } from '../../common/bad-input';
import { NotFoundError } from '../../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from '../../common/app-error';


import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';


@Component({
   selector: 'vr-dashboard',
   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
   animations: [...ROUTE_TRANSITION],
   host: { '[@routeTransition]': '' }
})
export class DashboardStatisticsComponent implements OnInit {

isLoadingResults: boolean;


constructor(
  private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
  private service: DataService,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.isLoadingResults = true;
this.service.getAll('/dashboard').subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.isLoadingResults = false;
}); 
}
}
```

**Data Service.ts**

```
  import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
  import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
  import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
  import { Http, RequestOptions , Headers } from '@angular/http';
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
  import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
  import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

  @Injectable()
  export class DataService {

    options: object;

    constructor( private http: Http , private toastr: ToastrService ) { 
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token'));
      this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    }

    getAll(url: string) {
      return this.http.get(environment.apiEndPoint+url,this.options)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    get(url: string) {
      return this.http.get(environment.apiEndPoint+url,this.options)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    create(url: string,resource) {
      return this.http.post(environment.apiEndPoint+url, JSON.stringify(resource),this.options)
        .map(response => {
           this.toastr.success( 'Data Saved Successfully');
           return response.json(); 
         })
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    update(url: string,resource) {
      return this.http.patch(environment.apiEndPoint+url , JSON.stringify(resource),this.options)
        .map(response => {
           this.toastr.success( 'Data Updated Successfully');
           return response.json(); 
         })      
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    delete(url: string,id) {
      return this.http.delete(environment.apiEndPoint+url,this.options)
        .map(response => {
           this.toastr.success( 'Data Deleted Successfully');
           return response.json(); 
         })      
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
      if (error.status === 403){
        //this.toastr.error( 'User Login Failed');
        return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
      }
      if (error.status === 500){
        //this.toastr.error( 'Internal Server Error');
        return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
      }
      if (error.status === 422){
        //this.toastr.error( 'Validation Failed');
        return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
      }

      if (error.status === 404){
        //this.toastr.error( 'Not found');
        return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError(error.json()));
      }

      //this.toastr.error( 'Something went wrong. Please contact Administrator!');
      return Observable.throw(new AppError(error.json()));
    }
  }
```

I am not understating what could be the issue. I can see all code executing without any issue.. But sometime(not all time) template is not updating the component variable changes and it is taking more time to load the it is keep on loading. IF I click the window anywhere , the data loaded immediately

http://edsee.wims.pro - This is the URL - Credentials- admin/123456 - password.. This issue is in all the modules

Please help me to find the route cause. Thanks in Advance. Also please tell me component to force the variable changes reflect immediately in template also. I hope my variable is not getting refresh immediately. because of that only it is keep on showing the loading. Once I click in UI it is triggering the variable changes and load the data immediately.

Comment: I tested it and get 404s presumably because of typos, in e.g. ../api/dedcutionCompensation

Comment: You can call angulars changeDetection for some case where they are not triggered. Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component, then at the right place (in your case after `this.isLoadingResults = false;`) you can call `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`. From your code I can see that you're already injecting it, have you tried this call?

Comment: oh btw you're also not reacting to any thrown errors of your subscription. You're catching errors in the `handleError` function of your service, but there you just throw a new error, which is never caught by you. After your `subscribe` call, you probably need to add another `catch` clause. I'm not sure what happens exactly, but you're setting `this.isLoadingResults = true;` but it won't be set to `false` in case of an error, only in case of success.

Comment: Your `data` model is getting dynamic object so html does not handle sometime. If you want to handle one way binding with dynamic data you should bind `data?.studentFeeDueToday` in your html where you set all data object similar like that.

Comment: I added `ChangeDetectorRef` in my code.. This is working well.. Thank toy @BenediktSchmidt for your suggestion..much appreciated..

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt Regading the service Actually I want to show notification for the Error and make is handled error.. which I could not do. Could not acccess `this.toastr.success( 'Data Deleted Successfully');` this function in my handle error.. any suggesion on that ?